# Altium - IDF importer doesn't recognize components with E* or H* designators

Tags: altium

I am trying to do the following:

I have created an IDF file (.emn) with details about where certain components should be placed, the shape of the board, keepout areas etc. and I'd like to import the information of the file to the Altium PCB.

But the problem is that somehow the components whose reference designators starts from E (that would be SFP cages at my design) or H (that would be LEDs) are not recognized and are not imported.

The connectors (which at my design have designators starting from X) and dip-switches (from S) are perfectly imported and placed.

Does anyone know how can we change the designator names that the importer understands? I haven't found any similar settings.

Comment: I used to use the IDF format with Circuitworks & Solidworks, and maintained a library of all the 3D models.  However, I came to the conclusion that putting the STEP model in the Altium footprint, then exporting a STEP file was a more sound way to go.